# index of matching items in parent element even if they're in other child containers

Tags: indexing, parent, children

I need to get the index of the li.play relevant to the ul.showreel_thumbnails. Is this even possible? All i seem to get is the li index inside ul.row

```
<ul class="showreel_thumbnails">
    <li>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="play_video">item</li>
        <li class="play_video">item</li>
        <li class="play_video">item</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
    <li>
       <ul class="row">
       <li class="play_video">item 4</li>
       <li class="play_video">item</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

so if item 4 is clicked it should give me the index of 4 etc...

best, Dan.

Comment: HTML is not a valid. UL inside a UL is wrong

Comment: updated. is that valid now or dont' i need the </li>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be valid HTML but here's how it would work (with JQuery):

```
function FindMyCount()
{
    var item_count = 0;
    $("#showreel_thumbnails li").each(function() {
        ++item_count;
        if($(this).hasClass("igotclicked"))
            return false;
    });
    return item_count;
}

$("#showreel_thumbnails li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("igotclicked");
    var myCount = FindMyCount(); // 1 - the # of li's under the showreel piece
    $(this).removeClass("igotclicked");
    // Do what you want here.
});
```

Comment: thanks, but creating an error after "return item_count;" 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return'

Comment: I updated the code snipet.  Sorry, i forgot to close out the click function and the .each function

Comment: agh - should of spotted that myself. Also added brackets to if($(this).hasClass("igotclicked")){  return false; } as didn't seem to be catching... thanks!